# call function in another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, call

I am trying to call another function in a different HTML file
would I do something like this:

```
 <script type = "text/javascript" src = "otherfile.html"></script>
```

This is the function getting called

```
        function rankedScores(music, pattern) { 
            var scoresArray = urlScores(music, pattern);  

            function swap(a, b) {
                var temp = scoresArray[a];
                scoresArray[a] = scoresArray[b];
                scoresArray[b] = temp;
            }

            for(var i = 0; i < scoresArray.length; i++) {
                for(var x = 0; x < scoresArray.length - 1; x++) {

                    if (scoresArray[x].score > scoresArray[x + 1].score) {
                        swap(x, x + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
            generateResults(scoresArray)
        }
```

This is how im calling it:

```
       rankedScores(albums, document.main.search.value);
```

Comment: Move it to a JS file.

Comment: If one of the pages is in an iframe, you can call its functions [from the parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this. You should move it into a `js` file and then include that `js` file in your template:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='some_other_file.js'></script>
```